# Sql Server Transaction Log Backup Fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, mirroring

I have a SQL Server 2008 Standard version. Mirroring is set up on the server in full safety mode. It has been working fine till today. The transaction log back-up fails every-time with an error

```
Error: 2014-09-25 08:34:33.17 Code: 0xC002F210 Source: JuneDB Log Backup Execute SQL Task
Description: Executing the query "BACKUP LOG [JuneDB] TO DISK = N'H:\BKs\Hou..." failed with the following error: "Read on "E:\LDFs\JuneDB.ldf" failed: 1(Incorrect function.)
BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly
```

- I am using a Maintenance plan for taking backups.
- The drive also contains log files of 5 other databases and their log backups are fine.
- This problem started after successfully completing rebuild indexes maintenance plan.
- Full backups do not have any problem.

I am not able to identify why reading the log file of this one database is erroring out. How am I supposed to proceed on this issue.

Things I tried

- Ran `DBCC CHECKDB([JuneDB]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS` returned no error messages
- Ran a query to take transaction backup instead of using a Maintenance plan. It gave same error

**Update** I just noticed at 4:30 AM we ran a maintenance plan to rebuild all indexes. Looking at the error log, I started getting errors for Transaction log backups after 4:30 Am. I am not sure how rebuild indexes could possibly cause the transaction log backups to fail but they sure seem related

Comment: What are you using to back up the transaction logs?  Maintenance plans? Or manually?

Comment: @Kris I am using a Maintenance plan

Comment: Have you tried a manual backup?

Comment: @joeqwerty - I tried and it manually and it gave same error "Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Read on "E:\LDFs\JuneDB.ldf" failed: 1(Incorrect function.)
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally.
"

Comment: OK, so at least you can rule out the maintenance plan as the problem then.

Comment: Are you using a UNC path? Doesn't appear to be but just want to make sure.

Comment: @Kris we are not using UNC path

Comment: Have you looked in the SQL Server log, the Windows event logs and the software for the RAID controller for filesystem-level problems, problems reading blocks, etc. Also, have you double-checked the file permissions on that file?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you every one for responding and helping me on this. It turns out be a log file corruption. Below steps solved my issue

- Stop mirroring
- Switching the database to the Simple recovery model
- Performing a checkpoint (which should clear the active log as long as nothing else requires the log to be kept active)
- Switching back to the Full recovery model
- Reestablishing the log backup chain by performing a full backup
- Start mirroring

http://sqlmag.com/blog/transaction-log-corruption-and-backups